# Getting an error [UIImage mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Working on JSON data and am extracting an image from the dictionary adding the image to an array

```
  NSURL *imageurl=[NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *) Dictionry[@"product"][@"image_medium_url"]];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    [self.productImageArray addObject:image];
```

And am copying this array to another array

```
for(int i=0;i<prodReq.productNameArray.count;i++)
{

    [productimageA addObject:[[prodReq.productImageArray objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy]];
}
```

And setting the image to an imageview

```
UIImageView *productimage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, prodimgY, 60, 75 )];
    productimage.image=[productimageA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And when I run the project am getting this error

```
 -[UIImage mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14581240
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding **UIImage** to the **productImageArray**. You dont need to add **mutableCopy** for a UIImage object. So just use

```
[productimageA addObject:[prodReq.productImageArray objectAtIndex:i] ];
```

Answer (score 4):

`UIImage` objects are immutable, so you can't call `mutableCopy` on them.